# Can I write "Jeden Tag stehe ich halb zehn auf."

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm trying to say that each day I get up at ten thirty in response to the question "Wann stehen Sie auf?" I'm having some trouble putting the words in the correct order though. Is "Jeden Tag stehe ich halb zehn auf" correct or horribly wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's very nearly fine (but I'm not a native speaker).  The only thing is that when you say something happens at a particular time, you need to add 'um' before the time (just like you add 'at' in English).

Also 'halb zehn' means half past nine rather than half past ten, so you need to say 'halb elf'.

"Jeden Tag stehe ich um halb elf [Uhr] auf" is grammatically correct, but to me "Ich stehe jeden Tag um halb elf auf" sounds better.